# URL with multiple anchor tag

Tags: tags, anchor

I have to build the URL that point directly to expedia review.
I think the best solution is to append to the URL multiple Anchor tag ID.

something like this:
http://www.expedia.it/Padova-Hotel-Hotel-M14.h4214808.Hotel-Information#reviews#BVRRDisplayContentReviewID_39211683

But it doesn't work, this url doesn't go directly to the user review.

Appending #reviews at the end of the URL the page tab is correct but i have to go directly to the user review using ID anchor Tag.

http://www.expedia.it/Padova-Hotel-Hotel-M14.h4214808.Hotel-Information#reviews

Reviews ID is BVRRDisplayContentReviewID_39211683

Does anybody knows how to hack this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually 'double-anchor'..

Best place to start is to read the existing share links they provide and then hack with 
that:

```
http://reviews.expedia.com/6510-<country/language site>/<hotel id>/review/<review id>/redirect.htm
```

e.g.
http://reviews.expedia.com/6510-it_it/4214808/review/39312750/redirect.htm

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer as correct.